# Tab-completion with directories/links

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link, autocomplete

I have this problem with tab-completion in terminal in both archlinux and ubuntu:

I have a link which links to a directory named "something" in my home directory. Now when I open a terminal and want to do something with that directory, let's say just `cd`, I'd type `cd somet` and then hit tab because now "something" is the only possibility it gets completed.

The problem is that there is no slash after something (as there should be since it's a link to a directory). I have to hit tab one more time for the slash to appear.

Is there a way to fix this, ie. so that the slash appears directly?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> `echo "set mark-symlinked-directories on" >> ~/.inputrc`
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

via [Ubuntu Forums - Strange bash shell tab completion behaviour](http://bit.ly/r5xp1B)

Comment: Noteworthy: this also works for OSX

Comment: Don't forget to include the default file in /etc/inputrc. Otherwise things like ctrl left won't work anymore.
$include /etc/inputrc

Answer (score 4):

I get the same behaviour, execpt I don't regard it as a bug/problem. The first completion is for the *link itself*, and the second is for the *link's target* (which happens to be a directory).

Consider this:

```
$ ssh devio.us
fredden@wolfman $ mkdir directory 
fredden@wolfman $ ln -s directory link 
fredden@wolfman $ ls -l link 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 fredden  shifty  9 Jun 21 18:03 link -> directory
fredden@wolfman $ ls -l link/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 fredden  shifty  512 Jun 21 18:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 fredden  shifty  512 Jun 21 18:03 ..
fredden@wolfman $
```

Comment: Would also say that this is a feature. This is 100% consistent treatment as with the difference between `rm something` and `rm something/`.

Comment: I see. So if it is by design, I assume there is no way around it? It's just that I have to cd to the dir/link quite often, and typing tab twice takes more time.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but <code>cd link</code> and <code>cd link/</code> yield the same results for me.

Comment: I believe the OP wants to cd into a subdir of link, so type "cd lin<tab>abc" to get "cd link/abc" rather than "cd linkabc" (i.e. not have to also type the slash), even though "cd link" and "cd link/" do behave identically.

Comment: and Roger Pate: yes, I know it behaves the same way, the problem is exactly as Roger Pate said. Oh well, I guess I'll have to type tab twice..