# Bash autocomplete on symlink to directory complete to whole directory, including slash

Tags: bash, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab-completion with directories/links](https://superuser.com/questions/155167/tab-completion-with-directories-links)

when I've a symlink `foo` linking to a directory `bar/` and I start typing `f` and hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, it completes to `foo` but I'd like to complete it to `foo/` so I can immediately add the next character for further completes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Enable the `mark-symlinked-directories` option for *readline*.

1. Edit `~/.inputrc`:

   ```
   $include /etc/inputrc
   set mark-symlinked-directories on
   ```
2. Press <kbd>C-x</kbd>, <kbd>C-r</kbd> to reload the settings.

See section *READLINE* in the manual page of `bash` for further documentation.

For those who do not wish to add another dot file, you can also add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
bind 'set mark-symlinked-directories on'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been dealing with the differences between OSX (defaults to `on`) and Linux (defaults to `off`) for months, and I finally got fed up enough to google it!  You're my new hero. :)

Comment: On some terminals C-x, C-r didn't work for me so I use `bind -f ~/.inputrc`

Comment: This shows the power of stackexchange combined with a simple answer and well-formulated question, answered my question in first attempt, got here via google, thanks. :)

Comment: what is this line `$include /etc/inputrc` for?

Comment: @razzak: Loads additional settings from that file, which usually has various standard keybindings for common terminals. (Usually they get loaded automatically, but if you have an `~/.inputrc` of your own, you need to load the system-wide one manually.) See section _READLINE_ in the manual page of `bash` for further documentation.

Comment: @grawity Thanks, i thought this happens by default for these type of files!, going to check manual pages for .bashrc and .vimrc now after reading this :-)

Comment: For some it does, for others it doesn't.

Comment: Would there be a problem with placing `set mark-symlinked-directories on` in the `/etc/inputrc' file itself?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you can do it exactly as you've described, but if you hit <kbd>tab</kbd> twice, it should complete the exapansion.